# Angular 9 fails to refer the global type I declared in a custom type definition file

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I've tried updating my angular project from Angular 8 to 9.

After the update, I entered `ng serve` to start up my app and it gave me these errors:

```js
src/app/core/components/server-map/server-map-container.component.ts:259:59 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ICoordinate'.

259     onContextClickLink({key, coord}: {key: string, coord: ICoordinate}): void {
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/core/components/server-map/server-map-change-notification.service.ts:52:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ITransactionDetailData'.

52             filter((data: ITransactionDetailData) => {
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/core/components/server-map/server-map-change-notification.service.ts:55:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ITransactionDetailData'.

55         ).subscribe((data: ITransactionDetailData) => {
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/core/components/server-map/server-map-change-notification.service.ts:58:82 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'INodeInfo'.
```

I suppose it's something to do with my custom definition file which occurs no error back in Angular 8. Anyway, I declared the types which I use across the app in `globals.d.ts.` under the `src` directory and let app the know it by referring it in `tsconfig.app.json` like:

```
"include": [
   "src/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

Again, there was no problem with this approach and I'm just wondering if something has changed internally which I didn't see from their migration guide. Any insight would be appreciated!